# Aplicar filtro em DataGrid preenchido com List sem alterar o DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, filtro

É possível aplicar filtro em um `DataGridView` que seja "preenchido" com um `List`, sem alterar o `DataSource` do grid?

Exemplo: Quando eu tenho um grid que usa um `BindingSource` eu posso aplicar um filtro, como `meuBindingSource.Filter = "coluna like 'valor%'"`.

Ou quando eu preencho o grid com um `DataTable` eu posso fazer `(dataGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "coluna like 'valor%'";`

Mas, quando eu preencho o grid com um `List` eu só consigo **simular** um filtro, porque acabo alterando o `DataSource` do grid. Ex.:

```
var source = ((IEnumerable<Tipo>)dataGrid.DataSource).ToList();
var ds = source.Where(x => x.COLUNA.EndsWith(filtro));
dataGrid.DataSource = ds.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diretamente na lista não tem jeito. O que você pode fazer é criar uma [`DataView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) conectando a lista para ela.

Tem uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839132/221800) mostrando como fazer isto (através de um `DataTable`).

Uma alternativa seria usar um controle de *grid* de terceiros que permita isto.

Não vejo outras formas agora além do que você já sabe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).